# HABTM relationship with "dependent: :destroy"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have 3 models in my test Rails 4 project.

1. Company
2. Project
3. Contact

A Company has_many Contacts and has_many Projects.
A Project belongs_to a Company.
A Contact belongs_to a Company.

I want to be able to create a relationship between a Project and a Contact.
There is the option to use the has_many :through relation but this will display all the Companies Contacts or Projects.

If I create a separate HABTM table i won't be able to use the "dependent: :destroy" option.

How can i make the relationship and let it be dependent on the company? So when i change the Contacts related company i won't have any corrupt data in my DB and all old relationships will be destroyed.

Comment: Project `has_many :contacts, :through => :company` should return only contacts of the company's project.

Comment: Yes, i agree. But i can not set only certain contacts for the project this way. This will give me all Contacts for the Project.

When creating or editing a Project i want to be able to select the contacts.
When creating or editing a Contact i want to be able to select the projects.